# Roman Numeral To Decimal

Tags: c

Trying to implement a very simple Roman Numeral to Decimal converter but can't seem to figure out a way for the program to return -1 if any non-roman numeral characters are in the string.  This is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int convertFromRoman(const char *s)
{

int i = 0;
int total = 0;

while (s[i] != '\0') {

    if (isalpha(s[i]) == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (toupper(s[i]) == 'I') {
        total += 1;
    }

    if (toupper(s[i]) == 'V') {
        total += 5;
    }

    if (toupper(s[i]) == 'X') {
        total += 10;
    }

    if (toupper(s[i]) == 'L') {
        total += 50;
    }

    if (toupper(s[i]) == 'C') {
        total += 100;
    }

    if (toupper(s[i]) == 'D') {
        total += 500;
    }

    if (toupper(s[i]) == 'M') {
        total += 1000;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

    i++;
}

if (total == 0) {
    return -1;
}

return total;
}



int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", convertFromRoman("XVII"));
    printf("%d\n", convertFromRoman("ABC"));
}
```

The first one should return 17 and the second one should return -1. However they both return -1 but if I remove the else statement, the first one returns 17 and the second one returns 100.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We don't solve homework for you. Probably not a good idea to have your first line as `//Homework`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @CharlieFish.  Wasn't asking anyone to solve it! Was just looking for some advice on what I was missing/reference me to some documentation.  Just put the homework in there so I didn't get a full answer as that's not a good way to learn!

Comment: use `else if`. (but your logic has wrong result of "IV" )

Comment: You should `return 0;` from `main` btw. (And technically use `int main(void)` if not using args.)

Comment: @RastaJedi Thanks man. Slipped my mind when writing quick tests :)

Comment: Why are you using isalpha?  This test does nothing for you - you have a complete set of characters you want to process

Comment: @Tibrogargan I wanted to make sure the string being passed in was of letters and nothing else. Soon as something that is not alpha is in the string, it is not a valid roman numeral and therefore should not be processed. Unless I am missing something in my understanding?

Comment: Off topic, but don't keep calling `toupper(s[i])` - do it once and reuse the results. Just imaging `toupper()` is some complex thing that takes 5 seconds, and you are calling it over and over with the same data...

Comment: @RastaJedi That's not strictly true. The C standard says `main` implicitly returns 0 if it does not have an explicit return. See the C11 standard or [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: @John3136 Thanks for that John. Very good point. Have amended my code :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks for the comment. This is a very simple program in which we only have to add up a string of letters and not worry about all of the roman numeral idioms.

Comment: @kaylum I was referring to C89... especially since that's what's portable to M$. Sorry for not being specific... I just always use that so I didn't really think twice.

Comment: have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: @KeithNicholas Yes have just done that now and seen my silly beginner mistake! Thanks :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Romans of 2000 years ago rarely consider IV to be 4, usualy they considered it 6.  More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_notation

Comment: @kaylum and what gcc uses by default (well technically gnu89 I guess it is?)

Comment: you should also consider changing your program so it does toupper once, making a function that returns a single letters value, and explore the wonder of "switch"  which is basically a big if else if else

Comment: @Mikey you have a set of known values that you intend to test against (you could be using a switch).  Anything outside that set is incorrect.  Why add two tests for incorrectness?

Comment: @chux did they just use 'IIII'?

Comment: @RastaJedi Yes! Great Wiki article on it

Comment: @RastaJedi See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Alternative_forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `if()` `if()` `if()` `else` to `if()` `else if ()` `else if()` `else`

```
   if (toupper(s[i]) == 'I') {
        total += 1;
    }

    else if (toupper(s[i]) == 'V') {
        total += 5;
    }

    else if (toupper(s[i]) == 'X') {
        total += 10;
    }

    ....

    else if (toupper(s[i]) == 'M') {
        total += 1000;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Or if you want OP you can use `switch (toupper(s[i]))` to make things a little simpler.

Comment: @RastaJedi There are _many_ potential improvements to OP's code.  For me, I would do something along [@Tibrogargan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38886941/2410359).  OP was having trouble with `if` `else if` `else`, so this answers focuses on that.  BTW it should be `switch (toupper((unsigned char) s[i]))` to avoid UB should `s[i]` be negative.

Comment: Yea I was just looking at his answer; it's pretty nifty. That's good to know... I only quickly opened the man and saw the prototype as `int toupper(int c);`, but I guess a lot of functions that work with characters specify them as `int` as well, don't they.

Comment: @RastaJedi  C11dr 7.4 discusses character handling functions including `isalpha()`, `toupper()`, etc. "In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."  This is why I recommended the `(unsigned char)` cast.

Comment: Yeah I see it in my man now it says something along the same lines as that, I just forgot for a sec that even things like `strchr()` or something that expects a char value has `int` in its prototype as well. (How come `scanf()` complains if you try to use an int argument but it won't the other way around? Is that just the way default arg promotions work?) Too bad I can't edit my original comment :P.

Comment: @RastaJedi `strchr()` is very useful for this type of problem.  Important to watch out for `strchr(string, 0)` which matches the the null character of `string`.  Do not expect `toupper(s[i])` in Tibrogargan answer to return 0 though.

Comment: I'm trying to implement it using a switch statement as well but am struggling to make it work. It keeps defaulting to -1. I can post what I have written if that helps?

Comment: @Mikey SO works best as _one_ question at a time.  Suggest making a new post (with a link back to this one for reference) posing the new issue about the `switch`.  Tip: enable all warnings in your compiler.  BTW: Suspect you are missing `break`.

Comment: @Mikey just a thought on the nature of roman numerals.  You're using -1 to indicate an error, but you could be using 0 since it cannot be represented by Roman numerals.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Assignment spec states we must return -1 if a value of 0 is returned somehow as it is not a valid roman numeral as you have pointed out.  Hence the if total == 0 check :)

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, just a bit of fun/alternate way of looking at the problem.  It does solve the problem if you're not considering ordering just adding "digit" values.

```
char *romanNumerals = "IVXLCDM";
int values[] = { 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000 };

int convertFromRoman(const char *s) {
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        char *idx;
        if (NULL == (idx = strchr(romanNumerals, toupper(s[i])))) {
            return -1;
        }
        val += values[idx - romanNumerals];
    }
    return val;
}
```